# Load XML text to paragraph

Tags: javascript

I want to load a few paragraph of text inside intro.xml to paragraph via jQuery.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "/xml/intro.xml",
  dataType: "xml",
  success: function (xml) {
    var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml),
        $xml = $(xmlDoc);
        $xml.find('intro').each(function () {
        $("p").append($xml.text());
    });
  }
});
```

The content of intro.xml:

```
<intro>
  Foo
  bar
  foo,bar
</intro>
```

Nothing shows up, and console doesn't show any error. What did I miss?

Comment: What does `console.log(xmlDoc);` output?

Comment: how to check the console.log? I'm using Opera beta.
If you mean the inspect element, on the console tab nothing shows up, no messages, no error, nothing.

Comment: Do you see anything if you add `error: console.log`?

Comment: no, nothing shows up. weird..

Comment: Are you able to check on the backend whether the request goes through?

Comment: i checked with simple request to return 200 code, and it works. I don't understand why this doesn't work..

Comment: What if you break the callback into intermediate variables and log each step of the way? Maybe it isn’t finding `intro` or something.

Comment: I think I found the source of problem, in my inspect element > sources, the xml folder isn't there, but when search it via windows explorer, the folder is present. What can be done to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I found it after fiddling with it. Apparently I am creating unnecessary callback to the XHR.

This is the original code:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "/xml/intro.xml",
  dataType: "xml",
  success: function (xml) {
    var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml),
        $xml = $(xmlDoc);
        $xml.find('intro').each(function () {
        $("p").append($xml.text());
    });
  }
});
```

This one shows result on the paragraph:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "/xml/intro.xml",
  dataType: "xml",
  success: function (xml) {
        $(xml).find('intro').each(function () {
        $("p").append($(this).text());
  }
});
```

I hope this may be of use to someone else.